# Turkish transit visa on arrival

Tags: visas, transit, turkey, uk-citizens, missed-flights

I'm flying from London to Mumbai in May, and then back from Kathmandu to London later in the month.  On both journeys I have a short (1-2 hours) stop over in Istanbul.  If everything works, I know I don't need a transit visa because there isn't time to leave the transit lounge at the airport.

However I'm concerned what happens if I miss my connection.  Obviously as I have a through ticket the airline will get me on a later flight and that won't significantly inconvenience my later plans.  But on my outwards journey I'm on the last flight to Mumbai of the day, so if I miss it, I'll have to spend the night in Istanbul.  If that happens, I'd rather pay for cheap hotel than try to sleep in the airport.  Is it possible to apply for a transit visa on arrival in those circumstances?

**Edit:**  I'm flying on a British passport, and there are no obvious reasons why I would be refused a visa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Officially Turkey no longer issues Visa-On-Arrival at any airports.  The Visa-on-Arrival has been replaced with an "e-Visa" which can be applied for electronically at http://www.evisa.gov.tr/

eVisas are generally issued immediately so you could potentially apply for one whilst in the airside area of the airport if you had internet access, however you will need access to your email in order to complete the application.

I am not aware of any alternatives, however it is possible that there is an exception process for people who have, for example, missed their flight.

Note that there is an air-side hotel in Istanbul Ataturk airport, however it's not cheap.